# problem in making connection with cassandra cluster with gossip snitch

Tags: cassandra

I'm having issue in making connection with 3 nodes cluster .i.e initially atleast 2 nodes are required to make connection with cluster is their any possible way where if all nodes are down and if **only One Node comes up** then i could make connection with cluster

below are the details of how i had setup the connection
cluster with 3 nodes using gossip snitch

**node1 cassandra.yml**

```
cluster_name: 'TestCluster'
num_tokens: 256
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
seeds: "1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3"
listen_address: 1.1.1.1
rpc_address: 1.1.1.1
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
network_authorizer: AllowAllNetworkAuthorizer
```

**Node1 rack.properties**

```
dc=datacenter1
rack=rack1
```

**Node1 topology.properties**

```
1.1.1.1=datacenter1:rack1
1.1.1.2=datacenter1:rack2
1.1.1.3=datacenter1:rack3
```

**node2 cassandra.yml**

```
cluster_name: 'TestCluster'
num_tokens: 256
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
seeds: "1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3"
listen_address: 1.1.1.2
rpc_address: 1.1.1.2
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
network_authorizer: AllowAllNetworkAuthorizer
```

**Node2 rack.properties**

```
dc=datacenter1
rack=rack2
```

**Node2 topology.properties**

```
1.1.1.1=datacenter1:rack1
1.1.1.2=datacenter1:rack2
1.1.1.3=datacenter1:rack3
```

**node3 cassandra.yml**

```
cluster_name: 'TestCluster'
num_tokens: 256
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
seeds: "1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3"
listen_address: 1.1.1.3
rpc_address: 1.1.1.3
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
network_authorizer: AllowAllNetworkAuthorizer
```

**Node3 rack.properties**

```
dc=datacenter1
rack=rack3
```

**Node3 topology.properties**

```
1.1.1.1=datacenter1:rack1
1.1.1.2=datacenter1:rack2
1.1.1.3=datacenter1:rack3
```

after this in node1 i connected to cqlsh with default username cassandra and password : cassandra

```
 CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS admin1 WITH SUPERUSER = true AND LOGIN = true AND PASSWORD = 'admin1password';
```

then i delete default user "cassandra"
Now from all three nodes i was able to connect to cqlsh via new admin1

Problem:

1. when all the three nodes are down --> later when one node is up --> **unable to connect to cqlsh**
2. when all the three nodes are down to make initial connection with cluster or connection to cqlsh it requires atleast 2 nodes to be up and running

can anyone please provide a solution for this issue

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use GossipingPropertyFileSnitch I would expect you to have edited the cassandra-rackdc.properties file on each node, just indicating which rack / DC that node belonged to. It would not contain details about the other nodes racks / DC's - the purpose of that snitch being that they would gossip to each other on their topology.

Specific problems you had:

1. If the system_auth keyspace was not changed to RF=3, then the details for the admin user you created are likely to be on a downed node, you need all 3 nodes to hold the authorization for the CL=ONE Admin auth to operate by being able to access 1 copy of the data.
2. This one is unclear, but any query issued at Local_Quorum / Quorum is going to want to see 2 of the 3 nodes up. I suspect though this is related to point 1, and you did not mention changing the RF of system_auth keyspace.

Comment: Thanks,

i tried this but issue still persist

Comment: Did you ensure the keyspace was repaired after changing the RF?